Is it true that for square matrices such that $CBC^{-1} = PBP^{-1}$ then $C = \lambda P$ where $\lambda \in F$ for some field $F$?
I was solving a problem where for a non-zero linear operator $T$ and two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that these matrices are the matrices of $T$ relative to the ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ respectively we have $A = PBP^{-1}$ where $P$ is some invertible matrix but not necessarily the change of basis matrix. I know that there exists a change of basis matrix $C$ such that $A = CBC^{-1}$ so $A = CBC^{-1} = PBP^{-1}$.
At first I assumed that $C$ would be the inverse of $P$ and tried proving that but realized that $P^{-1}CBC^{-1}P = B \iff P^{-1}CB = BP^{-1}C$ could be true with $P = \lambda B$. I know that if a square matrix commutes with every other matrix than that square matrix is a multiple of the identity, but I do not know that $P^{-1}C$ commutes with every other matrix. Is it true that $P^{-1}C = \lambda$? I cannot come up with a counterexample or a proof that this is true.

Let $P^{-1} C = S$.  This is an invertible matrix with $SBS^{-1} = B$, so $S$ commutes with $B$.  Any invertible matrix that commutes with $B$ would work.  For example, $S=B$ itself works if $B$ is invertible.  And then for any invertible $P$ you can take $C = P S = PB$.

That makes sense. Thank You!
